# ¿Se puede subir una aplicación React ya completa a WordPress?

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-plugin, wordpress-theme

Amigos.
Quiero subir una aplicación ya completa de React a un dominio ya comprado de WordPress. Hay alguna forma de lograrlo?
Solamente encontré como crear plantillas desde 0, que aun que no lo probé creo que no es lo que estoy buscando.
Espero tengan alguna idea de como lograrlo. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Creo que WordPress solo se dedica a hacer blogs. Ten en cuenta que una cosa es poseer un dominio y otra un servidor. En el caso de tener un servidor, puedes instalar WordPress en él o cargar lo que quieras.

Comment: Compraste un dominio en wordpress.com? si es asi, bastaria con redireccionar los DNS del dominio a los de tu instancia o host que contenga su app de react. Cambiando los servidores de nombre por los  de la ip de la instancia de tu app, sin embargo no he usado wordpress.com para la compra de dominios por lo que desconozco si es posible cambiar los servidores de nombre, pero en teoria no deberia de haber problema. Aqui una idea de como suele hacerse el proceso https://designplus.co/blog/diseno-web/apuntar-dominio-a-otro-hosting/

Comment: Si! tengo un dominio comprado por WordPress. Me lo dejaron asi y tengo que subir una app que hice en React. Muchas gracias la información esta muy buena buscare mas por ese lado